# How to get AWS S3 usage metrics by IAM user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch, metrics

How to get the usage metrics of S3.

Currently, IAM users are uploading/downloading files from the S3 bucket. Each IAM user has a separate folder. How to access, how many GB of data were transferred/downloaded from S3?.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. There is no such metric provided by AWS. You have to develop a **custom solution** for that. If you, for example, have CloudTrial trial enabled for S3 operations, you can parse the past logs and based on them build up a report on who downloaded/upload what. Once you know what objects were uploaded/downloaded by a give IAM user, you can add up their sizes.